# Вопросы по sip протоколу

Tags: sip

Я делаю свою реализацию библиотеки sip, потому что в чужих библиотеках не разобрался. но как я понял, что сама sip является только сигнальной, поэтому там нужно только реализовать http запросы и ответы. и вот. я прошел успешно `REGISTER`, и получил `200 OK` в ответ. что дальше? я звоню на мой номер, но мне не приходит сообщение. rfc книга большая и не понятно где об этом надо читать. там в книге вообще начинается с `INVITE`, а не с `REGISTER`, что было бы правильней. Может вы знаете что делать дальше?

Comment: А всё, догадался, надо было заголовок `Contact` заполнить.